# Is this lie okay in islam?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, tawba

I told a lie about being a victim of sexual abuse to a person that makes harsh comments about sexual abuse. However, I did this to stop them from making these comments as they were affecting the girls around me, due to some of them actually being a victim of such abuse. Is what I did unlawful, after telling him my lie I felt a sense of guilt, built ultimately said it stop him harsh comments. Is what I said unlawful?

Answer (score 1):

Islam forbids lying, with the exception of three scenarios that the Prophet (saw) specifically mentioned.

> Asma bint Yazid narrated that the Messenger of Allah said: "it is not
> lawful to lie except in three cases: Something the man tells his wife
> to please her, to lie during war, and to lie in order to bring peace
> between the people." Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1939

If your intention was to keep peace, then you have not sinned.

Answer (score -1):

Lying is considered bad except when we can save someone's life or prevent considerable financial loss.

Comment: So in this case lying ok? Answer this in your answer clearly.